# Nested collection with variable name

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to insert a collection inside a collection. Parent collection has it's name, but sub-collection will have a user-defined name (from a POST request).

I've tried it like this:

```
newInsert = jotc.newCollection.insert({'some':'data'})
```

where `jotc` is the existing parent collection. Instead of replacing `newCollection` with a value from a variable with the same name, MongoDB created a collection just like that: `jotc.newCollection`

Mongo version: 2.4.6
PyMongo version: 2.6.2
Python: 2.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have tried a little bit more before posting the question. Solution is to access the 'parent' collection dictionary-style:

```
newInsert = jotc[newCollection].insert({'some':'data'})
```

and it works.